# Retrieve default value for Optional Element in an XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, default, option-type

I have the following XML:

```
<Person>
   <Name>James</Name>
   <Age>18</Age>
</Person>
```

In the XSD that validates this XML, I want to add another element. I want this element to be optional but with a default value - so if it is missing when the XML is validated, it is populated with the default value. Let's say the new element is "NumberOfSiblings" which defaults to 0. I've done this like so:

```
<xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="NumberOfSiblings" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" default="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So now let's assume I come to parse the XML above in .Net / C#. Is there a way to validate it so it would automatically create the element with the default value, and therefore the parser would not fall over? If not, what's the correct way to obtain this default value from the XSD?

Comment: If you are using serialization you can add the default as a property in the class so it get initialized in the class constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately the codebase doesn't use a serializer. I think the only solution is for "NumberOfSiblings" to be an attribute, which will then be automatically generated when the XML is validated with addSchemaInfo set to true.

Comment: What is the source?  If it is in a class you can still initialize before creating xml.